# Dynamically Added Input Value disappear on next addition

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a webpage with ability to add input box dynamically , everything works fine. But whenever I add a new input box the value from all the input box added above that field get cleared automatically.

Here is the html which is generated on addition of the element

```html
<div class="main_text_area" id="got_id_from_server">
  <p>Add Delay For :</p>
  <div class="remove_bg button btn" name="some_id_from_server"></div>
  <p>
    <div contenteditable class="text_im" placeholder="Enter Delay" id="some_id_from_server" onchange="post_delay(this)"></div>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input class="text_im" placeholder="Select" type="text" id="some_id_from_server" list="some_id_from_server" onchange="post_delay(this)">
    <datalist id="some_id_from_server">
      <option value="Minutes"></option>
      <option value="Hours"></option>
      <option value="Days"></option>
    </datalist>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: show what you tried.

Comment: You'll be more likely to get a response if you share your code.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Huangism  I have edited the question . Added the input that I receive from the server and added on page

Comment: @Aana what's the code that adds the inputs?

Answer (score 0):

**This behavior occurs because adding new elements to your Dom will cause the Website to kind of render the view again & again so the (in this case) not stored values of a "input field given no ID attribute" you have inputted into your input-element will just reset.**

So have a look at this two code snippets:

```js
var count = 0;

function createInput(event) {
  count++;
  document.body.innerHTML += "<input value='Input #"+ count + "' / >"
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="createInput()">Create Input</button>
```

**Edit**: Using jQuery will be the better solution so have a look at this code (To prevent the reset of the input fields you have to use `"append()"`. **Try it on your own!**:

```js
var count = 0;
$(function() {
  $("#createInput").click(function(event) {
    count++;
    $('form').append('<input type="text" value="Input #' + count + '" />');
    event.preventDefault();
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" name="myForm" accept-charset="utf-8">
<button id="createInput">Create Input</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Hold your horses, the question has no code and the OP is a member since today. You are just providing another different solution when this doesn't solve the issue with OP's code which we have not seen